# Python parallel port read and send data

Tags: python, parallel-processing, port, virtual

By using the code

```
import parallel
p = parallel.Parallel() # open  virtual parallel port
```

I can open the virtual parallel port and change it's data.

I would like to know if it's possible to read the data of this port in other program?  This is because I want to simulate a program which is receiving data from a physical parallel port.

My system is: Linux Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Can you provide information on the environment you're running your code in?

Comment: Linux Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @FF10 welcome to stack overflow. when providing additional information, it is generally better to add it to your question and not as a comment

Comment: Ok, thank you. I have edited the question.

Comment: _**possible to read the data of this port in other program? **_: You mean on the same PC?

Comment: @stovfl Yes. I do not have any PC with parallel port at this moment. So i would like to do a simulation with virtual parallel ports.

Comment: Relevant: [simulation-of-parallel-port](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/24831/simulation-of-parallel-port-but-without-a-parallel-port)

Comment: @stovfl I read it before. It did not help me because I have to buy hardware.

Comment: The Answer claim: _**purely software solution**_.

Comment: They do not say that it is a pure software solution, but a capable one. And from what I understood, they are talking about the USB2LPT adapter.

Comment: I found this VPPSniffer [link](https://github.com/strezh/VPPSniffer) but it is not what I really want.  By the way, if you know a solution for Windows please tell me.